# home folder is read-only in ubuntu wsl

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was trying to build one of my projects, and I recently upgraded to windows 11. Does anyone have a solution? Also the rest of the file system isn't read only, just the home folder.

I tried reinstalling it, which made slightly better because i couldn't even save anything. But the compilation throws this error:

[image]

Comment: Was it dual boot?  Does the linux dual boot system use UEFI, Secure Boot and all the requirements for Windows 11?

Comment: it's ubuntu windows subsystem for linux, not a dual boot

Comment: WSL is different (upgraded) in Windows 11.  I have only used WSL once or twice, but I wonder if the upgrade affected your WSL install.

Comment: I don't know, but it may be a possibility

Comment: @Peregrino69 Alright, my bad. I will from now on

Comment: The headline isn't a good place to put your entire question, or if you do, also put it in the body. As it is currently written your question is unclear because it seems you need to read the title again midway through the first paragraph, and there still is a lot of assumed and missing information. Making your question more cohesive and complete will make it better, and better questions are more likely to get good answers.